# Вопрос закрыт как дубликат, но без ссылки на дублирующий вопрос

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, причины-закрытия, дубликаты

Наткнулся на вопрос
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/412024

```
отмечен как дубликат пользователем Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ 27 мар в 15:20
```

Но ссылки на дубликат нет.

Есть ли вопрос, для которого этот был дубликатом?

Или модератор у модератора не было под рукой подходящего вида заморозки, и он использовал "дубликат"?

По текущим правилам сайта, вопрос - "не по теме" и ему более подходит закрытие флагом "**Вопросы-опросники запрещены на Stack Overflow на русском.** Для получения ответа, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спасибо за замечание! Скорее всего, вопрос был закрыт до перехода на новый движок. В старом, не было возможности указать дубликат при закрытии.

Изменил причину закрытия.

Comment: Нашёл ещё один: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/395520/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83-2