# Кто может снять метку "дубликат"?

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов, дубликаты

Собственно что происходят с этими вопросами которые помечают как дубли и возможно ли удаление метки после редактирования?

Может стоит оставлять ссылку на дублирующий вопрос?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

upd 1.1 Ссылку вижу на сам вопрос, но он явно не является дублем.
Дубликаты автоматически получают минус?
кто их может снимать? 
могут ли несколько человек помечать дубликаты разные вопросы?

Comment: Так ссылка вверху вопроса всегда есть.

Comment: @Suvitruf, если постараться, то всякое можно найти, тут была тема на мете про дубликат без источника))

Comment: как вы комментируете удаленный вопрос?)

Comment: @ЕгорТрегубенко модератор же.

Comment: @Qwertiy можно пруф? D:

Comment: @Suvitruf, его уже открыли, перезакрыли и удалили. Но тема вот: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1095/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy отголоски хешкода)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вопросы-дубликаты остаются жить, если не попадают под [стандартные условия удаления](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2294/177221). В зависимости от рейтинга и от наличия комментариев, движок может удалить их через 30 дней, через год, или вообще никогда.

После редактирования вопрос попадает [в очередь на повторное открытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). Для открытия, как и для закрытия, нужно 5 голосов. В случае дубликата - достаточно одного голоса от участника с золотым знаком по метке, имеющейся у вопроса.

Дубликаты не получают автоматических минусов.

Ссылка на основной вопрос должна быть в плашке, но для некоторых старых вопросов она [потерялась при переезде с hashcode на stackoverflow](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1095/) несколько лет назад.

Comment: т.е автор вопроса не будет видеть сколько человек проголосовали "закрыть" ? тогда в чем разница между пометкой просто "дубликат" и выбором "закрытие по причине дубликат"?

Comment: Нет никакой отметки "просто дубликат". Есть состояние вопроса "закрыт" с причиной "дубликат" и ссылкой на существующий вопрос (или несколько существующих вопросов).

Comment: т.е метка [duplicate]  создает вопрос в специальной очереди - с вопросами, которые, вероятно, следует закрыть? а в какой момент он попадает в очередь "открыть повторно"?

Comment: @ЕгорТрегубенко в тот момент, когда кто-то предложит на вопросе открыть его повторно. У закрытого вопроса появляется такая ссылка.